# rails generate migration error mongo_mapper not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper

Follow [Installation in Rails 3 of Mongo Mapper](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/getting-started/rails.html) i add to config/application.rb file :

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.orm :mongo_mapper
end
```

when `rails generate migration my_migration` i got :

```
error  mongo_mapper [not found]
```

but when `rails generate model my_model`, i got a fine model class with `include MongoMapper::Document` and this output :

```
invoke  mongo_mapper
create    app/models/user.rb
invoke    test_unit
create      test/unit/user_test.rb
create      test/fixtures/users.yml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have migrations while working with MongoDB.
Because MongoDB is a schema less database.
That's the reason you can't generate migrations with mongo mapper.